# Are there two distinct rate limits for the Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube has stated that there's a [rate limit](https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#operation%5Flimits) for their API. And that's totally fine and understandable. However, it appears that, even respecting their rate limit and following their [best practices](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html) is insufficient. In the YouTube [terms of service](http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms), section 4H states that "You agree not to use or launch any automated system, including without limitation, "robots," "spiders," or "offline readers," that accesses the Service in a manner that sends more request messages to the YouTube servers in a given period of time than a human can reasonably produce in the same period by using a conventional on-line web browser"

So YouTube has an API to automate certain actions, but you have to limit yourself to an ill-defined notion of some human equivalent. Would following the best practices (in particular, waiting 10 minutes after any "too_many_recent_calls" 403 suffice to obey 4H?)

In my particular application I intend to upload tens of thousands of videos to my YouTube channel, and I'm concerned that even obeying the best practices will still result in YouTube terminating my account without explanation.

(For those concerned that tens of thousands of videos is spammy and illegitimate, I assure you that this is not the case. These are not advertising any product, and according to a couple hundred test case uploads, these are videos which people like much more often than dislike and which have high audience retention. For an example of such a channel (not mine), see http://www.youtube.com/user/EmmaSaying)

Answer (score 0):

The terms of use you linked (containing the 4H section) is for the YouTube website. The API has a [different set of terms](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) and you can check the quota information [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).